# insert batch only insert the last id enter entered?

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

I am trying to insert multiple checkboxes.

When I insert 2 or more checkboxes, it only shows the last checkbox i entered. The other checkbox i checked was not entered in the sql table.

**My Model**

```
public function addBatch($data, $feetype_id) {
    $this->db->trans_begin();
    if (isset($data['id'])) {
        $this->db->where('id', $data['id']);
        $this->db->update('fee_session_groups', $data);
        $fee_session_group_id = $data['id'];
    } else {
        $this->db->insert('fee_session_groups', $data);
        $fee_session_group_id = $this->db->insert_id();
    }


    $feeGrouptype_array = array();
    foreach ($feetype_id as $month) {

        $session_id     = $this->setting_model->getCurrentSession();
        $amount         = $this->input->post('amount');
        $penalty        = $this->input->post('penalty');
        $fee_groups_id  = $this->input->post('fee_groups_id');
        // $start_date     = $this->input->post('start_date');
        // $end_date       = $this->input->post('end_date');

        $vehicle_array[] = array(
            'fee_session_group_id' => $fee_session_group_id,
            'feetype_id' => $month,
            'fee_groups_id' => $fee_groups_id,
            'session_id' => $session_id,
            // 'start_date' => $start_date,
            // 'end_date' => $end_date,
            'amount' => $amount,
            'penalty' => $penalty,
        );
    }   
    $this->db->insert_batch('fee_groups_feetype', $vehicle_array);
    $ids[]=$this->db->insert_id();
    if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE) {
        $this->db->trans_rollback();
    } else {
        $this->db->trans_commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you put $this->db->last_query(); right after that insert_batch and post the result so we can see the sql that is being run?

Comment: ^ in addition to that, it would be helpful to see your view as well as a `print_r($feetype_id)`

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.